# Two targets One UNIVERSAL app

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have an iPhone Xcode project, I duplicated my app target, now I have two targets:
1. For iPhone
2. For iPad

How to build one app from these two targets? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't, you need to change on target into a universal app.

An universal app is just one app, not two apps. In the project file you can set the `iOS Application Target` to `Universal`.
This will make the app run on both the iPhone and iPad.

The system can automaticly load the correct nib file if you use the `~ipad` in the nib name, for example `AboutViewConntroller.xib` for iPhone and `AboutViewConntroller~ipad.xib` for ipad.

This when you can still load the viewcontroller like:

```
AboutViewConntroller *viewController = [[AboutViewConntroller alloc] initWithNibName:@"AboutViewConntroller" bundle:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to have two target just two nib files with diffrent names and in init method do thi :-

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    NSString *nibName=nil;
  (isiPad?)nibName=@"Course_iPad":nibName=@"Course";
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

OR

```
HelpPeiceSetting *objHelpPieceSetting=[[HelpPeiceSetting alloc] initWithNibName:isiPad?@"HelpPeiceSetting_iPhone5":@"HelpPeiceSetting" bundle:nil];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:objHelpPieceSetting animated:YES];
            [objHelpPieceSetting release];
```

at time of pushing the obj.

Comment: in your case it will be an iPad xib though

Answer (score -1):

You can select different target from the Scheme drop down menu at top left corn close to RUN, STOP button. If you don't have those option available, you can select "Edit Scheme" from Scheme drop down menu, and duplicate schemes for different target.